# Finding the smallest solution for a pair of two variable equaitons?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Consider two equations over two variables (in Reals) of the form:

$f(x,y) = 0$

$g(x,y) = 0$

The maximum degree of both equations is 2 and the number of terms in each equation is at most C (say C=4). But the equations are not necessarily simple polynomials. It can also include trigonometric identities like $sin(x)$, $cos(y)$ etc.

For eg (just a random example):

$f(x,y): sin(x)*cos(y) + sin(3x) - cos(5y) + x = 0 $

$g(x,y): x - 3y = 0$

would qualify as a degree 2 equation with 4 terms and degree 1 equation with 2 terms.

**Query:** Given that we have 2 equations, exactly 2 unknowns with maximum degree of each term is 2, is it always possible to find the smallest solution to such a problem (assuming one exists). The smallest solution might be defined as smallest absolute value of x and y?

I think it should ( possibly using Root finding methods like Newton Raphson etc??) be but need a confirmation?

Comment: The concept of degree is only applicable to polynomials. Your example equation does not have degree 2, nor does it have any other degree.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I do not know what other technical term to use. Let me put it this way: in each term of each equation there are at most two 'directions of freedom' i.e. each term can be changed by changing the value of two variables. I did code for Newton Raphson but it works when the guesses are very close and if the constants are large then it becomes somewhat useless.

Comment: There is no correct term to use, because the thing you are talking about is not a thing at all. Essentially, you ask how to solve an equation of arbitrary form. That's a question as broad as math itself.

Comment: I fail to see how two two variable equations would represent arbitrary form. can you please elaborate? The number of equations are exactly 2. The number of variables are exactly 2. Number of terms are at max some constant C. And each term has a "degree of freedom" (not degree in technical sense) at most 2.

Comment: OK, you ask how to solve a system of two equations in two variables of arbitrary form. Unless of course you severely restrict the allowed tool set. Can we use the gamma function? What about exponential function? What about $\sin x^2$ (not $\sin^2x$)?

Comment: I think we are making it deliberately complicated. Lets say anything composed of constants, simple variables and sin() and cos(). The parameters of sin and cos being simple variables or their  power etc. i.e. other simple polynomials (like you pointed x^2). nothing else.

Comment: So, no $\exp$, no $\ln$. That's the severely restricted tool set I was talking about. With these clarifications, your question is no longer as broad as math itself. Pity it doesn't help us much. Many things can be said about simple polynomials, or trig polynomials, but as soon as you have $x$ and $\sin x$ walking hand in hand (and then $\sin x^2$ on top of that!), you are out of luck. Numerical methods are our only resort.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks for confirming. Newton Raphson does so but very close near the root. otherwise it needn't even converge or is painfully slow to the point of being useless.  Is there a numerical method approach that is guaranteed to converge in this specific scenario? And if possible at a reasonable speed?

Comment: Long story short, there is no silver bullet. Every method has its limitations.